# What is the default color when I run the paint method

Tags: java, swing, paint

im drawing a bargraph with this paint method, and the bars a a dark gray. I just wanted to know how to get that color back when i change back and forth?

is there a Color.DEFAULT or something like that?
Or should i just setColor before the the loop

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < barsArray.length; i++, k += getWidth()
        / barsArray.length) {
        g.fillRect(k + 5, getHeight() - barsArray[i] * 15, getWidth()
            / barsArray.length - 1, getHeight() * 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use `g.getColor()` before you change it.

It might not be suitable to override `paint`, instead, you should consider overriding `paintComponent` of a class that extends from `JComponent`

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't "just setColor ...", since the Graphics object you receive as an argument is shared by the component hierarchy right to the window that contains it.

You have two options (basically):

1. Store the current color into a variable and restore it once you're done (preferable if you have very few state changes to the Graphics object):

`Color oldColor = g.getColor();`

`// do something with g`

`g.setColor(oldColor);`

1. Clone the graphics object and dispose of the clone once you're done (preferable if you have a lot of state changes to the Graphics object):

`Graphics gCopy = g.create();`

`// do something with gCopy`

`gCopy.dispose();`